# Explorer plugin to view/edit files inline

Tags: windows, text-editor

I'm looking for a Windows explorer plugin that will enable me to view and edit text files inline (or in a small dialog) without the need to open it in an application first.

I edit a load of .properties and .conf files on a daily basis and this would save me a ton of time!

Thanks.